# SB Audigy 1 ES [SB0160] on OpenSuse 15.2 no microphone

Tags: linux, audio

There is unresolved trouble with this souncard. No microphone in KDE plasma applet and system settings. But card also has this connector. How resolve it ?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the proper and newest Linux driver for the audio device?  This is most likely what you must do.

Comment: I use in distro. Which command to check ?

Comment: Try this:   https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-do-i-check-driver-versions-in-linux